# How to bind ApplicationDbContext to a View in ASP.Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I need to bind ApplicationDbContext to my View for using models but its not working.

I have tried @using ProjectName.Data for accessing ApplicationDbContext but vain.

@using TailorManagementSystem.Data in the head

ApplicationDbContext dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();

The error comes out to be 
"There is no argument given to that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of ApplicationDbContext"

Comment: Why you need context and also who you create your context ?

Comment: You should use the `Context` in your Controller to use models and then pass them to the view.

Comment: @UxmaanAli i want to create the object of applicationdbcontext so that i can access my database in views

Comment: @JLe i have used context in my controller but here i wanted to access my database in views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to *inject* it into the view:

```
@inject TailorManagementSystem.Data.ApplicationDbContext Context
```

Then you can use `Context` in your view.

However, you should *never* actually do this. Views should have as little logic as possible. Things like querying a database should be handled in your controller action or via something like a view component, never in the view itself.